# GET Request for SVG by jQuery gives 500 Internal Service Error

Tags: apache, svg

I am using a jQuery/SVG map to create points on a world map. After linking jQuery and the javascript libraries I run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map').mapSvg({
            source: 'maps/world_high.svg',
            width: 600,
            height: 350
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly on my localhost running the same apache version. But when I upload it to my website it does not render and firebug gives me this error:

[image: error message]

**EDIT**

When I access the map and view it like:

```
http://www.domain.com/maps/world_high.svg
```

It loads the map in the browser, when I go back to the page, the map works. Somehow apache is blocking the GET request but im not sure how or why.

Comment: Is there anything in the server's error log?

Comment: I don't have access to the server error log as I am using 3rd party hosting.

Comment: Can you expand the request to see any other headers or parameters that are sent?